# How to translate a variable template ( random value ) in django

Tags: python, django

I want to build a website using Django. My website supports two languages, English and Vietnamese.

In models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Order_product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    note = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices = [('Pending', 'Pending'), ('Need-Delivery', 'Need-Delivery'), ('Delivery', 'Delivery'), ('Success', 'Success'), ('Return-Order', 'Return-Order'), ('Cancel', 'Cancel')])
```

In views.py i have code like that

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def test(request):
    get_order = Order_product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'test/test.html', {'get_order ':get_order})
```

In template test.html

```
{% for each_order in get_order %}
   <p>
       {% blocktranslate %}
           {{ each_order.status }}
       {% endblocktranslate %}
   </p>
{% endfor %}
```

after that, i run : python manage.py complimessages. In django.po file i have :

```
msgid ""
"\n"
"                        %(each_order.status)s"
"                        "
msgstr ""
```

I want to translate the template variable each_order.status based on its value. If the variable each_order.status has the value 'Success,' it should be translated to 'Thành công' in Vietnamese, ... How can I use Django for translation? I've done a lot of research but haven't found a suitable solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Define a `translations` variable that contains supported languages. Each language is represented by mapping of code-level phrases (e.g. "Success" value of `each_order.status`) to translated values. Then in template use the translated values, passing the language you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TextChoices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

in .py

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models

class Status(models.TextChoices):
    PENDING = "Pending", _("Pending")
```

in .po

```
msgid "Pending"
msgstr "translation"
```

Don't forget compilemessages and LocaleMiddleware

[Display choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

in .html

```
{{ obj.get_status_display }}
```